# Navigation bar not switching tabs in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

When I click on an item on the navigation bar the fragment associated with it does not open. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj5Rd_GCQkY&t=144s) tutorial and did exactly the same thing except for file names. I updated android studio and changed Gradle plugins to the latest versions.

**Main Activity**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    navController=Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.activity_main_nav_host_fragment)
    setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationView,navController)

}  
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
```

**nav_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_main"
app:startDestination="@id/journalFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/journalFragment"
    android:name="com.example.dreamjournalai.JournalFragment"
    android:label="fragment_journal"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_journal" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:name="com.example.dreamjournalai.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="fragment_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/storeFragment"
    android:name="com.example.dreamjournalai.StoreFragment"
    android:label="fragment_store"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_store" />
</navigation>
```

**nav_menu.xml**

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:title="Journal"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_book_24"
    android:id="@+id/journal_fragment"/>

<item
    android:title="Profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
    android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"/>

<item
    android:title="Store"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_local_grocery_store_24"
    android:id="@+id/store_fragment"/>

</menu>
```

**fragment_journal.xml**

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".JournalFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="First"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment example**

```java
class JournalFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, container, false)
}
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Please include you navigation XML file

Comment: Hello, included navigation XML file

Comment: Your IDs between your navigation XML file (`journalFragment`, etc.) don't match your menu XML file (`journal_fragment`, etc.). They need to match.